# How do I extract a single value from df.corr() in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, correlation

I have a dataframe that has 2 levels of columns which looks like this:
[image]

I want to identify the correlation between cases and rate for each country - excluding all rows where the value is 0 (whether cases or rate) as these are outliers and not relevant.

I have a loop I run the country_df.corr() in and can see what I want.  If I could grab the specific value I'm after then I could probably store that in a list with the country name - which is what I want to do.  I just have no idea how to pull the specific value out of the correlation matrix

I will then select those entries from the list that have a value greater then 0.5 or more probably less than -0.5.  The relationship is expected to be inverse - as vaccination rate goes up we expect cases of measles to go down.

Here is the loop code:

```
df=df2.unstack().fillna(0)
for country in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    country_df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c[0] == country]]
    for c in [c for c in country_df.columns if c[1] in ['Cases', 'Rate']]:
        country_df = country_df[country_df[c] > 0]
    print country_df.corr()  # Instead of printing whole correlation here I just want to store the country name & cases/rate correlation
```

Any help gratefully appreciated

here is the code to create this dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({u'Afghanistan': {(2000L, 'Cases'): 6532.0,
  (2000L, 'Pop'): 19702000.0,
  (2000L, 'Rate'): 27.0,
  (2001L, 'Cases'): 8762.0,
  (2001L, 'Pop'): 20641600.0,
  (2001L, 'Rate'): 37.0,
  (2002L, 'Cases'): 2486.0,
  (2002L, 'Pop'): 21581200.0,
  (2002L, 'Rate'): 35.0,
  (2003L, 'Cases'): 798.0,
  (2003L, 'Pop'): 22520800.0,
  (2003L, 'Rate'): 39.0,
  (2004L, 'Cases'): 466.0,
  (2004L, 'Pop'): 23460400.0,
  (2004L, 'Rate'): 48.0,
  (2005L, 'Cases'): 1296.0,
  (2005L, 'Pop'): 24400000.0,
  (2005L, 'Rate'): 50.0},
 u'Albania': {(2000L, 'Cases'): 662.0,
  (2000L, 'Pop'): 3122000.0,
  (2000L, 'Rate'): 95.0,
  (2001L, 'Cases'): 18.0,
  (2001L, 'Pop'): 3114000.0,
  (2001L, 'Rate'): 95.0,
  (2002L, 'Cases'): 16.0,
  (2002L, 'Pop'): 3106000.0,
  (2002L, 'Rate'): 96.0,
  (2003L, 'Cases'): 8.0,
  (2003L, 'Pop'): 3098000.0,
  (2003L, 'Rate'): 93.0,
  (2004L, 'Cases'): 7.0,
  (2004L, 'Pop'): 3090000.0,
  (2004L, 'Rate'): 96.0,
  (2005L, 'Cases'): 6.0,
  (2005L, 'Pop'): 3082000.0,
  (2005L, 'Rate'): 97.0},
 u'Algeria': {(2000L, 'Cases'): 0.0,
  (2000L, 'Pop'): 31184000.0,
  (2000L, 'Rate'): 80.0,
  (2001L, 'Cases'): 2686.0,
  (2001L, 'Pop'): 31600800.0,
  (2001L, 'Rate'): 83.0,
  (2002L, 'Cases'): 5862.0,
  (2002L, 'Pop'): 32017600.0,
  (2002L, 'Rate'): 81.0,
  (2003L, 'Cases'): 15374.0,
  (2003L, 'Pop'): 32434400.0,
  (2003L, 'Rate'): 84.0,
  (2004L, 'Cases'): 3289.0,
  (2004L, 'Pop'): 32851200.0,
  (2004L, 'Rate'): 81.0,
  (2005L, 'Cases'): 2302.0,
  (2005L, 'Pop'): 33268000.0,
  (2005L, 'Rate'): 83.0},
 u'Andorra': {(2000L, 'Cases'): 2.0,
  (2000L, 'Pop'): 65000.0,
  (2000L, 'Rate'): 97.0,
  (2001L, 'Cases'): 5.0,
  (2001L, 'Pop'): 68200.0,
  (2001L, 'Rate'): 97.0,
  (2002L, 'Cases'): 1.0,
  (2002L, 'Pop'): 71400.0,
  (2002L, 'Rate'): 98.0,
  (2003L, 'Cases'): 0.0,
  (2003L, 'Pop'): 74600.0,
  (2003L, 'Rate'): 96.0,
  (2004L, 'Cases'): 0.0,
  (2004L, 'Pop'): 77800.0,
  (2004L, 'Rate'): 98.0,
  (2005L, 'Cases'): 0.0,
  (2005L, 'Pop'): 81000.0,
  (2005L, 'Rate'): 94.0},
 u'Angola': {(2000L, 'Cases'): 2219.0,
  (2000L, 'Pop'): 15059000.0,
  (2000L, 'Rate'): 36.0,
  (2001L, 'Cases'): 9046.0,
  (2001L, 'Pop'): 15629800.0,
  (2001L, 'Rate'): 65.0,
  (2002L, 'Cases'): 11945.0,
  (2002L, 'Pop'): 16200600.0,
  (2002L, 'Rate'): 66.0,
  (2003L, 'Cases'): 1196.0,
  (2003L, 'Pop'): 16771400.0,
  (2003L, 'Rate'): 52.0,
  (2004L, 'Cases'): 29.0,
  (2004L, 'Pop'): 17342200.0,
  (2004L, 'Rate'): 52.0,
  (2005L, 'Cases'): 258.0,
  (2005L, 'Pop'): 17913000.0,
  (2005L, 'Rate'): 32.0}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the correlation matrix will always be ordered the same for the data you gave, so it will look like

```
                Angola                    
                 Cases       Pop      Rate
Angola Cases  1.000000 -0.500364  0.779077
       Pop   -0.500364  1.000000 -0.274885
       Rate   0.779077 -0.274885  1.000000
```

and so you can just select the value you want with `.iloc()` Just create a dictionary (or list or whatever you want) before the loop and append the country and the value to it with the correct locations.

```
corr_dict = {}
df=df2.unstack().fillna(0)
for country in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    country_df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c[0] == country]]
    for c in [c for c in country_df.columns if c[1] in ['Cases', 'Rate']]:
        country_df = country_df[country_df[c] > 0]
    corr_dict[country] = country_df.corr().iloc[0,2]

corr_dict
#{'Afghanistan': -0.6404117984998553,
# 'Albania': -0.12115398350489878,
# 'Algeria': 0.5031318694416725,
# 'Andorra': -0.6933752452815364,
# 'Angola': 0.779077493398456}
```

Comment: Just brilliant! - works perfectly thank you - and another concept added to my data wrangling knowledgebank.  I tested it with the list you mentioned first - but I can certainly see why doing it as a dict works even better.

Comment: Yeah, it all depends what you want to do with it. You could even just make it into a `DataFrame` making it easy to just keep using all of the pandas methods with it. `corrdf = df.from_dict({'corr': corr_dict})`

Comment: Interestingly enough - that is exactly what I did - but I did it in a slightly less pythonis way:  correlation = pd.DataFrame(corr_dict, index=['correlation'])  It worked - but then i needed to transpose it.  Your comment has even given me more data for the data wrangling knowledgebank - I would suggest that is a valuable part of the answer and you might want to add it in?